# Problems with using Shallow cloning in GitLab and Git diff

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having trouble using GitLab's Git strategy and shallow cloning. I need to perform a Git diff to compare a main branch with another branch I created.

This is my configuration:

[image]

And this is the job I use to do gif diff:

```
lint:
  stage: lint
  image: selenium-runner:7.0.33
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  tags:
    - k8s
  before_script:
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci/
    - composer install --no-ansi --ignore-platform-reqs
  script:
    - echo "-- Checking PSR on new files --"
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - git fetch origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
    - if [ "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" != "" ];
      then git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME -- '*.php' ':(exclude)*.blade.php' |
      xargs -rd '\n' ./.gitlab-ci/vendor/bin/phpcs || true;
      fi
```

But I get this error:

[image]

To do the diff I fetch the prod branch as shallow cloning does not clone all branches:

```
    - git fetch origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

but I have the problem I show above in the second picture.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the shallow clone (**--depth 20**) to fetch only the last commit. When I compare the main branch and the MR (Merge Request) branch, I can't do it because the branches are not in the repository. I forced a fetch from origin/master and then executed "**git diff origin/master..CI_COMMIT_BRANCH**" or maybe I can use "**git diff origin/master..HEAD**".